# how do i get my navigation in line with the logo?

Tags: css, html, navigation

i have the following code, right now just a logo in a div, but i'm trying to add a few navigation cells that i will later style. the problem is, i can't seem to get them "in line" with (meaning besides) the logo, they always drop down to the next line. what am i doing wrong?

```
    #header {
    position:relative;
    padding-top:0px;
    width:960px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    }
    #nav {
    padding:0px;
    height:20px;
    }
    #nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    }
    #nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

    <div id="header">
    <img src="logo3.png" height="91" width="162">
            <div id="nav">
            <ul>
            <li>nav item 1</li>
            <li>nav item 2</li>
            <li>nav item 3</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, http://jsfiddle.net/PLmSB/1/

*Tested in Chromium*

You just had to add

```
#nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top; /*optional*/
}
```

Be sure to read this article on [Cross-Browser Support for Inline-Block](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)

Otherwise, as @Ana pointed out,

```
img {
    float: left;
}
```

This should work. http://jsfiddle.net/PLmSB/3/

Comment: i tried that but unfortunately the menu is still a line lower than the logo.

Answer (score 0):

You should float the logo. http://dabblet.com/gist/3118980